# Closed Loop Transfer Function For Negative Feedback Circuit

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, negative-feedback

I have the following circuit diagram

[image]

I understand the open loop circuit (H<sub>1</sub>H<sub>2</sub>H<sub>3</sub>H<sub>4</sub>) and I also understand the negative feedbacks H<sub>1</sub>H<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub> ,   H<sub>3</sub>H<sub>4</sub>H<sub>5</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>H<sub>3</sub>H<sub>7</sub>, but I can't figure it out why the positive feedback H<sub>1</sub>H<sub>2</sub>H<sub>3</sub>H<sub>4</sub>H<sub>5</sub>H<sub>6</sub> takes part in the closed loop response.

Can someone explain me this? Also, are there any rules or algorithms that would help me simplify this diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Do you see what I've done here: -

[image]

I've moved the H7's input to H4's output and, in doing so, I have to reduce the input to H7 by H4 to make things equal. **This then allows the function inside the red box to be simplified.**: -

[image]

Step and repeat in several other areas and it should all easily resolve into a final formula.

> *Can someone explain me this? Also, are there any rules or algorithms
> that would help me simplify this diagram?*

Redraw, redraw and redraw until you get one block.

Moving the output of H7(s)/H4(s) to the left-most input: -

[image]

If you followed how I got to here, the rest is trivial.